# The "right" way to use write Slick 3.0 Scala queries in Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I'm using Slick 3.0 and (of course) almost all the examples out there cover Slick 2.x. Things have changed and frankly seem **more** complicated, not less.

Here's an example: I want to get an object (a GPPerson) by id. This is what I have right now, and it seems **very** verbose... more so than Slick 2.x:

```
def get(id: GPID): Option[GPPerson] = Await.result(
    db.run(
        people.filter(_.id === id).result), Duration.Inf
    ).headOption
```

In Slick 2.x things were easier because of the implicits, among other things. But the above seems to be the most concise expression I've come up with.

It also doesn't really address exception handling, which I would need to add.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're blocking your thread with `Await.result`. You're probably aware but it's just scary seeing it in code.

Comment: I'm aware – and all of the Slick 3.0 examples from Typesafe do this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I started to use Slick 3.0 in a new project a few months ago and I had the same questions. This is what I understood:

Slick 3.0 was designed for non-blocking asynchronous (reactive) applications. Obviously it means Akka + Play / Spray nowadays. In this world you mostly interact with Futures, that's why Slick's *db.run* returns Future. There is no point in using Await.result - if you need blocking calls it's better to return to 2.x.

But if you use reactive stack you'll get benefits immediately. For example, Spray is completely non-blocking library that works with Futures nicely using [onComplete](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.3/spray-routing/future-directives/onComplete/#oncomplete) directive. You can call a method that returns Future with a result from Slick in a Spray route and then use that result together with onComplete. In this case the whole response-reply pipeline is non-blocking.

You also mentioned exception handling, so this is exactly how you do it - using Futures.

So based on my experience I would write your method in a following way:

```
def get(id: GPID): Future[Option[GPPerson]] = db.run(
  people.filter(_.id === id).result.map(_.headOption)
)
```

and then work with a Future.

Comment: Is the Future returned directly in an Action? Right now, for instance, I have a few Actions that use Await to complete the query. For instance, I'll do `val r = db.run(glimpleAction); Await.result(r, Duration.Inf)` in the Action... would I just take out the Await and Play is smart enough to manage the consequences of that? (But it can't be that simple, because I can do `Await.result(r, Duration.Inf).toSeq` to get a sequence. How would I return a Future in a web service Action?)

Comment: You definitely don't need Await.result. Standard way of writing queries in Slick for me: `db.run(some_query.result)` and this will return type `Future[Seq[SomeQueryType]]`. 
Regarding Play - you need to use `Action.async` to be able to use Futures inside your actions, more details: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaAsync

Answer (score 1):

you can do this.

```
def syncResult[R](action:slick.dbio.DBIOAction[R, slick.dbio.NoStream, scala.Nothing]):R = {
    import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

    val db = Database.forConfig("db")
    try {
      Await.result(db.run(action), Duration.Inf)
    } finally db.close
  }

def get(id: GPID): Option[GPPerson] = syncResult { people.filter(_.id === id).result.headOption }
```

Comment: Okay, that does make it a little bit cleaner... but as pointed out above, what about the fact that this is a blocking call? It seems that **all** the Slick 3.0 examples I've looked at use this pattern but... it's blocking. That seems very wrong. Also it seems like Slick 3.0 has gone in the wrong direction, making things harder to call rather than easier... but perhaps there are changes in the API that I just haven't found. The documentation is, to be kind, "vague and incomplete..."