# Is Managed Blocking needed for nested Scala Futures?

Tags: java, scala, concurrency, akka, future

For my fork-join-pool (the default global) to be able to allocate new threads, if I have nested Futures, do I need to wrap all the individual Futures with blocking {...}, if they are DB calls or other I/O  / Network processes for example?

Which is correct?

```
Future.sequence(
   blocking{
      val f1 = Future(...)
      val f2 = Future(...)
      val f3 = Future(...)
      for (x <- f1; y <- f2; z <- f3) yield List(x, y, z)
   }
)
```

or

```
Future.sequence(
  val f1 = Future(blocking{...})
  val f2 = Future(blocking{...})
  ...
)
```

EDIT:

I think this test (which prints "Futures done" then 8 sleeping lines, wait 5s, 8 sleeping lines, etc.) shows that individual blocking calls need to use the managed blocking wrapper:

```
val locked =
   Future.sequence {
      blocking {
         (0 to 100).map { i =>
           Future {
             val idx = i
             println(s"I'm sleeping: $i")
             Thread.sleep(5000)
             println(s"I'm awake: $i")
          }
       }
    }
 }
println("Futures done")
```

Comment: `blocking {}` doesn't really have to do with Futures at all. It is used to wrap a block of code which is likely to block (IO, Wait, etc) to signal to the executing thread that there will be blocking happening. Since the execution of the code in Future.apply is executed *outside* of the encoding block, it will have no effect on the code passed to Future.apply.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the implementation.
If the implementation of DB access or IO is blocking then you should wrap them in `blocking`.

The `blocking` should be done within each `Future`. Cause they will start to run instantly.

Side note: Using the `global context` for production code is no good idea.
 You should define separated execution contexts optimized for your usecase.

For your slick usecase you can find details here: http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/database.html#database-thread-pool

Comment: I use Slick's db.run() method which returns a Future, but I know JDBC is blocking, so I assume they must already handle that threadpool expansion or thread sharing problem somehow? Is it possible that you have to throttle your requests to their threadpool?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30339825/the-right-way-to-use-write-slick-3-0-scala-queries-in-play-framework .